# Subquery in Active Directory Query

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

I'm trying  to get  a list of users   from a  OU  in Active  Directory, and one of the fields I'm trying  to get  is  the "Manager" field,  as well as other fields in for Every user in AD.  The returned  data  for  the manager field  is  the  `DistinguisehdName` and I want to get  the  `DisplayName`  for the  manager.  Can  I  make  a sub query  in the main query  to get  `DisplayName`  for  the manager field ?

How can I  go about this ?  Also,  even if  my  filter  includes specific properties  I  get  back  added  properties to my  data  like  `SID`, user `DistiguishedName, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID`. How  can I get  rid of those ?

This is  the  command im runing

```
$result =@()
$result+= Get-ADuser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SomeOU,OU=MAinOU,DC=Local,DC=WAN" -properties City,Company,Country,countryCode,Department,Description,DisplayName,Division,EmailAddress,EmployeeID,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute10,extensionAttribute11,extensionAttribute12,extensionAttribute13,extensionAttribute14,extensionAttribute15,extensionAttribute2,extensionAttribute3,extensionAttribute8,GivenName,HomePhone,mail,Manager,MobilePhone,Name,Office,OfficePhone,Organization,SamAccountName,State,StreetAddress,Surname,telephoneNumber,Title,UserPrincipalName

$result | Export-Csv -Path .\Users.csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a hashtable that maps the `DistinguishedName` value to the corresponding ADUser object:

```
$Properties = 'City,Company,Country,countryCode,Department,Description,DisplayName,Division,EmailAddress,EmployeeID,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute10,extensionAttribute11,extensionAttribute12,extensionAttribute13,extensionAttribute14,extensionAttribute15,extensionAttribute2,extensionAttribute3,extensionAttribute8,GivenName,HomePhone,mail,Manager,MobilePhone,Name,Office,OfficePhone,Organization,SamAccountName,State,StreetAddress,Surname,telephoneNumber,Title,UserPrincipalName' -split ','

$AllUsers = Get-ADuser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SomeOU,OU=MAinOU,DC=Local,DC=WAN" -Properties $Properties

$UsersByDN = @{}
$AllUsers |ForEach-Object { $UsersByDN[$_.DistinguishedName] = $_ }
```

Now you can use `$UsersByDN` to look up the manager's ADUser object and grab the display name based on the `manager` attribute value:

```
$AllUsers |Select -Property @($Properties;@{Name='ManagerName';Expression={$UsersByDN[$_.manager].DisplayName}})
```

Comment: Hey  Thanks  this  helped  !